# barrier for N threads with a semphore

Tags: c

I wrote the following short application for solving the barrier problem.
This application should guarantee that three identical threads, running the same thread method,  will all "meet" at a common code section.
I ran it and it seems ok.
My question is:

1) is it correct ?

2) Is there a preferred and efficient way to implement it for N threads ?

here is the code:

```
static sem_t t_1_sem;

static sem_t t_2_sem;

static sem_t t_3_sem;



struct my_thread_info {
    int num;
};

void *thread(void *vargp)

{

        struct my_thread_info *info = (struct my_thread_info*)vargp;
        static int counter=0;
        counter++;

        if (info->num == 1) {
                printf("info->num=%d\n", info->num);
                if (counter<3)
                    sem_wait(&t_1_sem);   // down
                else {
                    sem_post(&t_2_sem);   // up
                    sem_post(&t_3_sem);   // up                 
                }

        } else 
            if (info->num == 2) {
                printf("info->num=%d\n", info->num);
             if (counter<3)             
                    sem_wait(&t_2_sem);             
                else {
                    printf("info->num=%d\n", info->num);
                    sem_post(&t_1_sem);
                    sem_post(&t_3_sem);    //up             
            }
            } 
            else  
            if (info->num == 3) {
                printf("info->num=%d\n", info->num);
             if (counter<3)             
                    sem_wait(&t_3_sem);             
                else {
                    sem_post(&t_1_sem);
                    sem_post(&t_2_sem);    //up             
            }
        }
        printf("meeting occured!\n");

}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid0, tid1, tid2;

    struct my_thread_info info1, info2, info3;
    info1.num = 1;

    sem_init(&t_1_sem, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&t_2_sem, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&t_3_sem, 0, 0);

    pthread_create(&tid0, NULL, thread, &info1);
    info2.num = 2;

    pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thread, &info2);

    info3.num = 3;
    pthread_create(&tid2, NULL, thread, &info3);


    pthread_join(tid0, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid1, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2, NULL);   
    pause();
    return 0;

}
```

regards
Kevin

Comment: See also the pthread_barrier_XXX functions if you only need barriers.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your `counter` variable is unguarded - u have a possible race condition when doing `counter++`. Use a mutex;

As for doing N threads - using an array of threads/semaphores is IMO acceptable, I have code which utilizes that design and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

1.No it is not correct. Doing increments like `counter++;` will cause race condition and it won't increment the counter properly. You'd want to surround it with a critical section.

2.

```
static pthread_mutex_t cs_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static sem_t t_sem;

void *thread(void *vargp)
{
    static int counter=0;
    pthread_mutex_lock( &cs_mutex );
    counter++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &cs_mutex );

    if( counter == NO_THREADS )
        sem_post( &t_sem );

    sem_wait( &t_sem );
    sem_post( &t_sem );
}
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){

    pthread_t tids[NO_THREADS];
    sem_init( &t_sem, 0, 0 );

    for( i=0; i<NO_THREADS; i++ ){
        pthread_create(&tids[i], NULL, thread, NULL);
    }

    for( i=0; i<NO_THREADS; i++ ){
        pthread_join(&tids[i], NULL);
    }
    pause();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't your `counter` access in the condition unsafe? And how does your answer differ from mine, anyway? :P

Comment: I thought the OP needed something more concrete...? `if( counter == NO_THREADS )` is fine since we don't care about the positive values of the semaphore.